# Migrate DownloadString WebClient() single-thread calls to Async calls

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous

I want to convert a very static `DownloadString()` call to a `DownloadStringAsync()`, but can't get the flow as I'd like.

Currently, I do the following in *lots* of places:

```
string apiurl = "http://api.gowalla.com/spots/" + spot;
var entries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SpotInfo>(CallGowalla(apiurl));
return entries;
```

With the `CallGowalla` looking like so:

```
private static string CallGowalla(string apiurl)
        {
            var wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
            wc.Headers["ContentType"] = "application/json";
            wc.Headers["Authorization"] = CreateAuthorizationString();
            wc.Headers["-Gowalla-API-Key"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api"].ToString();
            var raw = wc.DownloadString(apiurl);
            return raw;
        }
```

I'm getting hangups on the the calls, so I want to move the `DownloadString` to `DownloadStringAsync` and I'm not sure where to start without ripping apart all the calls to `CallGowalla` throughout.

Any ideas?

Suggestions on architecture and refactoring welcome also...

Comment: is this a win app or a web app?

Comment: why not just move those calls to a background thread? Are you sure you want async calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to think about how you are calling the CallGowalla() method. It is probably easier to start calling this method in an async manner. Take a look at some of the examples on [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315582) Microsoft KB article. Your CallGowalla() method is equivalent to LongRunningMethod() in those samples.

Running methods asynchronously, perhaps using additional threads, can be problematic in some environments like ASP.NET. It is important to research issues dependent upon your environment. If you are trying to get higher throughput (more calls to Gowalla) then you might want to look into use of the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to execute your method without managing threads. The problem with this is that you might exceed the Gowalla API limits very quickly. It would be good if you could provide more detail on why you need to make these calls asynchrously.

If you need a good overview on threading with C# there is a [free book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) available.

Comment: thanks for the response. The primary reason for the Async calls is because my application can sometimes lock within its thread whilst it awaits a response from Gowalla.  I have considered using a seperate thread to do this - but I'm not sure of which avenue is best practice.  Will look at the Microsoft KB article you provided... +1

Comment: the Microsoft KB article was a lifesaver and got me just what I needed.  The 'free book' is also a goldmine of information. Many thanks.